# Shortest Google Sheets formula to detect if cell contains an image

Tags: code-golf

**Step one**

In a new google sheet insert an image into cell A1 with

Insert > Image > Image In Cell

**Step two**

Create a formula to return TRUE (if the cell contains an image) and FALSE (if the image is missing)

**Rules**

Only vanilla formulas are allowed. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Your first question is OK, however it is never a good idea to post a super short answer to your own question immediately; you could, however, post it as a comment on your challenge and give brownie points to anyone who beats it. Next, answers should be scored by *bytes*, not characters. Finally, [tag:text-processing] isn't relevant to this challenge. I recommend you read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions and try posting competitive answers too.

Comment: As a challenge, this is completely fine. I'd consider making this a [tag:tips] question, honestly, but it's not a bad challenge.

Comment: Will excel formulas and VBA be ok?

Comment: Is the cell empty if the image is not there, or might it contain other non-image content?

Comment: @Wasif This question is google sheets only since I do not believe excel allows images inside cells like google sheets, at least exporting the google sheet to excel pushes the image outside of the cell.

Comment: @xnor so basically the cell might contain anything that is permissible in google sheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 26

The shortest I've found, which I believe currently works, is:

```
=TYPE(A1)>64>ISFORMULA(A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
The way it is checking is if there is an image no data(Text) could be found so....:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(IFERROR(IMPORTDATA(A1),FALSE)),IMAGE(A1),"There is no Image there")
```

A1 = is the Image URL (https://....jpg)

Comment: Although this formula seems to identify image URLs correctly, it doesn't follow the rules set out in the challenge. A1 is supposed to contain the image itself (not a URL) and the formula is supposed to return TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

### 13 bytes

```
=TYPE(A1)=128
```

The other answer is looking for other values.  You asked for just a test true/false if an image in the cell.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375?hl=en-GB&sjid=11934302938886193323-NA